# How do I break up a bibliography into separately numbered sections?

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

There are at least two use cases where one might want to list items in a bibliography under separate subsections with different numbering conventions.

- a CV, where you'd like to list journal papers, conference papers, workshop papers, etc under different categories (often needed in academic settings);
- an annotated bibliography, where you might need different sections for different topics being covered.

What I'd like is a method that allows me to specify names of subsections, and for an added bonus, different numbering conventions for each subsection, and then will list `\cite`s in different sections as per my wishes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your use cases, I tend to use the `bibentry` package. As the focus is not really on providing a reference mechanism (i.e. `\cite`'s), but actually on *listing* the content of these bibliographical entries, this package works really nice.

Using LaTeX lists you can style your output in whatever way you want, and the `\bibentry` command allows you to typeset the content of a bibliography entry wherever you want in your document.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know that it will do all that you ask, but the [multibib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/multibib.html) package will get you at least some of it.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers will all succeed, but I'd go with [biblatex](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). It was a number of features for bibliography subdivision, for example by keyword, and if designed from the start for flexibility.

Comment: I love biblatex. I'm always surprised how few people use it. I guess it's because bibtex and the various packages mentioned above are pretty good at most things, so no one needs to change. I hope one day biblatex will become the standard.

Comment: biblatex is still very much being developed, and one of the things there is a relative shortage of is styles (there are hundreds of styles for standard BibTeX, and currently only about 10 bundles of biblatex styles on CTAN).

Answer (score 2):

A handy package that I use is `splitbib`. It allows all of the above, and gives customized section titles and numbering schemes for different parts of the bibliography. It's pretty easy to use - all you have to do is specify a list of bibtex cites for each subsection, as well as a name for the section, and optionally a prefix to use when numbering the references in each section.