# Headings inside the bibliography list?

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

Is it possible to have headings inside `thebibliography`? I need to categorize the references into, say, "required" and "optional".

I tried simply putting some text in between `\bibitem`s, but the compiler complains about encountering text not part of a `\bibitem`.

A solution not involving BibTeX is preferred for now, I'm still learning LaTeX and for the paper I'm writing I only have a handful of references (and not that much time, surprise-surprise :-). I plan to learn BibTeX in the future, of course.

Just before posting I looked at [How do I break up a bibliography into separately numbered sections?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222/how-do-i-break-up-a-bibliography-into-separately-numbered-sections) and one of the answers was mentioning [`multibib`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/multibib.html) which appears to have such functionality. I'll ask anyway in case there are other solutions, I just need some extra text displayed, not to really break the bibliography into subbibliographies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you don't like to use BibTeX, here's a solution simply using the standard bibliography environment.

You could use the `\item` command to insert headings or text into a bibliography, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{KnuthXX}
\item[]\hspace{-\labelwidth}\hspace{-\labelsep}\textbf{Required}:
\bibitem[Knuth86]{DK86} D.E. Knuth,
  The TeXbook, 1986
\item[]\hspace{-\labelwidth}\hspace{-\labelsep}\textbf{Optional}:
\bibitem[Knuth89]{DK89} D.E. Knuth,
  Typesetting Concrete Mathematics, 1989
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: references]

Or use two bibliography environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Required}
\begin{thebibliography}{KnuthXX}
\bibitem[Knuth86]{DK86} D.E. Knuth,
  The TeXbook, 1986
\end{thebibliography}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Optional}
\begin{thebibliography}{KnuthXX}
\bibitem[Knuth89]{DK89} D.E. Knuth,
  Typesetting Concrete Mathematics, 1989
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, and want to add text between the bibliography title, and the first bibitem. I tried the solution with the \item command. It works for headlines, but not for several paragraphs of text, since the layout is messed up. How can I correct that? (I use the AMSbook class)

Comment: @Britzel [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Answer (score 3):

I have several categories of references in my CV. I used `bibunits` and I'm pretty happy with how that came out. I've never tried writing a bibliography by hand though, so I have no idea how much trouble that would be. I highly recommend learning BibTeX. It won't take very long at all, especially if you have a sample to look at.

Comment: Another possibility is `multibib`; I'm using it in my CV.