# Adding text between Bibliography header and the first bibitem

Tags: bibliographies

I want to add text in to the Bibliography right after the header and before the first bibitem, so that it is structured as in the following:

> References and further reading
>
> This and that can be found in [1]. The other stuff is particularly
>   well explained in [2] and [3]. ...
>
> [1] ... [2] ...

(As you can see, I also want to have the header saying "References and further reading", instead of "Bibliography, but this I already managed to do that by renewing the `\bibname` command.)

A similar question was discussed and answered here: [Headings inside the Bibliography list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/headings-inside-the-bibliography-list). The simplest solution was to add the text with the `\item` command, such as:
`\item[]\hspace{-\labelwidth}\hspace{-\labelsep}Here is the text.` While this does work for headers, it does not for one or several paragraphs of text, since the layout is messed up.

Can anyone tell me how I can do this? Would be glad if there was a simple solution, but am happy for any help, thanks! :)

Some more information on my document:
I use the `AMSbook` class. The document consists of three parts, where each one has it's own bibliography, created with the `thebibliography` environment. I do use the `\hyperref` package, and want all Bibliographies to be properly displayed (clickable) in the table of content, which works fine as it is now.

**EDIT - Comments on the answers of Gonzalo Medina and Guido:**

Both these approaches work, thanks! I have chosen to use Guido's approach, since it is simpler as long as one has no problem with using the `natbib` package. Anyway, both methods produce equally good results and fit directly to my needs, thanks! :)

Comment: With biblatex you can use the `\defbibnote` command. Are you using biblatex? If so I will write up this explanation.

Comment: Got already two working approaches. Thanks anyway ;).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `natbib` package has a `\bibpreamble` hook. You can populate the text with `\renewcommand{\bibpreamble}{<text>}`.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\bibpreamble}{First. This and that can be found in~\cite{testa}. 
  The other stuff is particularly well explained in~\cite{testb} 
  and~\cite{testc}.}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{testa} Test A.
\bibitem{testb} Test B.
\bibitem{testc} Test C.
\end{thebibliography}

\renewcommand{\bibpreamble}{Second. This and that can be found in~\cite{testd}. 
  The other stuff is particularly well explained in~\cite{teste} 
  and~\cite{testf}.}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{testd} Test A.
\bibitem{teste} Test B.
\bibitem{testf} Test C.
\end{thebibliography}

\renewcommand{\bibpreamble}{Third. This and that can be found in~\cite{testg}. 
  The other stuff is particularly well explained in~\cite{testg} 
  and~\cite{testi}.}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{testg} Test A.
\bibitem{testh} Test B.
\bibitem{testi} Test C.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**
For the font `\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}` changes the font (size) for the bibliography (but not the preamble).

Comment: Your code produces errors. You shoud use `\renewcommand` instead of `\newcommand`. Also, the OP is using `amsbook`, so perhaps you should also consider changing the document class in your example.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina thanks for the suggestion. The code does not produce an error in my system (natbib 2000/07/24 7.0a (PWD), MacTeX 2012). I get an error with `\renewcommand`.

Comment: Hi there and thanks for the answer! Please see the EDIT in my start post. :) (The answer was too long for a comment.) Btw, I also had to use `\renewcommand`also for the first time; seems to be a version-thing.

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution; in the code below I defined a `\bibNote` command that allows the placement of text after the heading and before the first bibitem; the font for this note can be changed by redefining the `\Notefont` command (default value `\normalsize`). A redefinition of `\bibname` allows to change the heading.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\renewcommand\bibname{References and further reading}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Notefont{\normalsize}
\long\def\bibNote#1{\gdef\@bibNote{\item[]{\Notefont#1}}}
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
  \@xp\chapter\@xp*\@xp{\bibname}%
  \normalfont\footnotesize\labelsep .5em\relax
  \renewcommand\theenumiv{\arabic{enumiv}}\let\p@enumiv\@empty
  \list{\@biblabel{\theenumiv}}{\@bibNote\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
    \leftmargin\labelwidth \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \usecounter{enumiv}}%
  \sloppy \clubpenalty\@M \widowpenalty\clubpenalty
  \sfcode`\.=\@m
}{%
  \def\@noitemerr{\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist
}
\makeatother

\bibNote{This and that can be found in~\cite{testa}. The other stuff is particularly well explained in~\cite{testb} and~\cite{testc}.}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{testa} Test A.
\bibitem{testb} Test B.
\bibitem{testc} Test C.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If `babel` is being used, the redefinition of `\bibname` has to be done using `\addto\captions<language>`; for example, if the document contains

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

one has to say

```
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand\bibname{References and further reading}}
```

Comment: Hi there and thanks for the answer! Please see the EDIT in my start post.(The answer was too long for a comment) :)

Comment: @Britzel I've updated my answer. Now you can control the font for the note using `\Notefont`.

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work:

```
\renewcommand\bibname{References\\
\normalsize{} Citation data collected from Scopus 
(Elsevier) Sep. 6 2017.}
```

An example:

```
\documentclass\[a4paper,12pt\]{report}

\renewcommand\bibname{List of books\\ \vspace{10mm} \normalsize{} Note: Strindberg has also written other books.}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}

One book written by Strindberg is Hems\"{o}borna \cite{book1}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{book1}
    August Strindberg, \textit{Hems\"{o}borna}, 1887.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome, this might work, but it is not really a sleek way to achieve the result ;-)

Comment: Can you make your snippet into a small but compilable example? A screenshot of the output would be nice as well. Right now, your answer is in the Low Quality review line, but it is a quick fix most LaTeX users would use. I say the answer should stay, but it needs a bit improvement.