# Adding "Further Reading" section at the end of automatically generated bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

First off - the facts. I'm using the `report` documentclass and `unsrt` bibliographystyle, with Jabref to manage all the references.

The question - I'm working on my thesis and need to add a section like 'Further Reading' to my bibliography. I want to add this at the END of the already generated bibliography. I found [this code (the 2nd answer which creates a bibnote)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70946) but it adds the text before the first bibitem whereas I want it at the end (unfortunately I'm on a deadline so I dont have time to play with it and figure it out myself).

As an extra bonus, the articles that need to go in further reading have not all been cited in the text. I can use `\nocite` to make sure they get a reference number, but if anyone has any suggestions so that I could either have them listed with something like bulletpoints, or renew the numbering so that the 'Further reading' starts with 1 would also be great.

[edit for more info]: I'm using bibtex. If it matters, I'm using Texnic Center as the editor and compiling straight to PDF

Comment: I'm using bibtex. If it matters, I'm using Texnic Center as the editor and compiling straight to PDF.

Comment: Search for the `{subdividing}` tag: there's lots of questions related to this.  You'll also find better answers if you have the time and willingness to switch to `biber`+`biblatex`.

Comment: have you tried to pput the text directly after the `\bibliography` command?

Comment: jon - thanks for the tip - sometimes knowing what to look for is part of the problem

guido - tried that, doesnt work.

Comment: Fyi relating: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376091/list-uncited-references-in-the-bibliography

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you're "on a deadline", switching to `biblatex` is somewhat risky. Instead, use `multibib` as shown in the following MWE (it works with the `unsrt` style). Optionally, use the `resetlabels` package option.

Note: Unless you're using tools like `latexmk`, compile the example with

```
(pdf)latex <filename>
bibtex <filename>
bibtex further
(pdf)latex <filename>
(pdf)latex <filename>
```

using the command line (standard compiling routines of editors like TeXnicCenter won't do).

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{further}{Further Reading}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sectionbiblio}{%
  \patchcmd{\std@thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section*}{}{}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Some text \cite{A01,B02}.

\nocitefurther{C03}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{biblio}

\sectionbiblio

\bibliographystylefurther{unsrt}
\bibliographyfurther{biblio}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: right. got it to work! last thing, any way i could have the further reading on the same page as the references? right now its on a new page. (this is just nitpicking though, im just happy to have it work!)

Comment: @perdita Should it look like a standard (unnumbered) chapter in other respects, or would you like it to look like a section?

Comment: a section please :)

Comment: @perdita Answer updated.

Comment: Brilliant. Answer has been upvoted accordingly, but I'll still say thanks again!