# List uncited references in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I have 300 references. I cited 230 of them. In the **References** it shows 230 references. Now, how can I list the remaining 70 references in a **Bibliography** section.

Note: I don't want

```
 \nocite(*)
```

as it will list all 300 references. I only want to list the un-cited 70 references.

Comment: Do you use `biblatex`?

Comment: I think so
  
  
 \usepackage[backend=bibtex,natbib=false,sorting=none,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex} 
     \addbibresource{references.bib} % The filename of the bibliography
     \nocite{*}

Comment: Do you want [How to split bibliography into “works cited” and “works not cited”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6967/35864)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do it, filtering with the field `keywords={nocite}`:

```
 \documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, sorting=none, style=numeric-comp, defernumbers]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{myownlittlebiblio.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[keyword=cite,heading=subbibliography,title={Cited papers}]%
\printbibliography[keyword=nocite,heading=subbibliography,title={Supplementary papers}]

    \end{document}
```

The `.bib` file:

```
@book{B1,
  author = {Name1, Surname1},
  title = {Title of the first book in the  \emph{Cited}  category},
  publisher = {Name of the Publisher},
  year = {2017},
  keywords = {cite}
}
@book{B2,
  author = {Name2, Surname2},
  title = {Title of the  book in the \emph{Not cited} category},
  publisher = {Name of the Publisher},
  year = {2016},
  keywords = {nocite}
}
@article{A1,
  author = {Name3, Surname3},
  title = {This is the title of first article in the \emph{Cited}  category},
  journal = {Name of the Journal},
  year = {2017},
  volume = {01},
  number = {12},
  pages = {1-20},
  keywords = {cite}
}
```

[image]

If you want independent numbering of the subbibliographies, add the option `[resetnumbers]` to the `\printbibliography` commands:

[image]

Comment: I think the quesiton was how to do it automatic.

Comment: @KcFnMi But it automatically put the \cite{}d references in the "Cited papers" and \nocite{*}d references in Supplemetary papers.