# A simple implementation of comment/verbatim: drawbacks?

Tags: verbatim, grouping, catcodes

While considering how to exclude `\items` in Yossi Farjoun's recently active question [onlyitems? How to select specific items from an item list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4502/575), I thought I would do what I proposed in my first answer: just comment them out.  That had a clunky syntax, however, so I did something else.

But I thought of a simple way of doing comments that avoids the clunky syntax and elaborate parsing that the `comment` environment of the `verbatim` package goes through: just set all the catcodes to "ignore" (that is, 9).  You have to restore them, of course, so this should be done in a group, and since TeX can't see the end of a group when everything is ignored, you have to leave braces intact.

It is a little clunky to set *all* the catcodes, but since I was using `pgfkeys` already it was natural to employ its `.list` handler to do the looping for me.  Users of multibyte-character systems might want to change the definition of the `utility/change all characters` key in the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgffor}

\pgfkeys{
 /comment/.is family, /comment,
 utility/set catcode/.code 2 args = {\catcode#1=#2},
 utility/ignore character code/.style = {utility/set catcode = {#1}{9}},
 utility/verbatim character code/.style = {utility/set catcode = {#1}{12}},
 utility/change all characters/.style = {utility/#1 character code/.list = {0,...,255}},
 ignore all characters/.style = {utility/change all characters = ignore},
 all characters verbatim/.style = {utility/change all characters = verbatim},
 restore braces/.style = {
  utility/set catcode = {`\{}{1},
  utility/set catcode = {`\}}{2}
 }
}

\def\ignoreallcharacters{\pgfkeys{/comment/.cd, ignore all characters}}
\def\allcharactersverbatim{\pgfkeys{/comment/.cd, all characters verbatim}}
\def\restorebraces{\pgfkeys{/comment/.cd, restore braces}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
The following is ignored.

{
 \expandafter\ignoreallcharacters\restorebraces
 This stuff should all be ignored.
}

\noindent
This should be printed again.  Now we have verbatim text:

{
 \tt
 \expandafter\allcharactersverbatim\restorebraces
 This should be verbatim.     This should have a large space before it.
}

\noindent
And normal text again.
\end{document}
```

As a bonus, it's not hard to do the same thing to get verbatim text.  A little more work could probably make things look nicer (for example, doing the equivalent of `\obeyspaces` and `\obeylines` rather than printing them as "other" characters) but the principle is there.

So, my question: what are the drawbacks of this approach to commented/verbatim input?  Even Knuth, in the TeXbook, doesn't suggest doing this.  (He does point out that this *kind* of method will not allow unbalanced braces, but it's not hard to make `restore braces` turn some other pair of characters into the group delimiters, and then we're looking exactly like what `\verb` usually does.)

Comment: You can't use this with an already tokenized input, unless you process it again with `\scantokens`.

Comment: @egreg: You can't use *any* verbatim environment with already tokenized input unless you reprocess it with `\scantokens`.

Comment: Using `pgf` here is a _massive_ overkill, which makes this method quite inefficient. You just need a `\loop...\repeat` construction. Also, it might be slightly more efficient to give catcode `14` to all characters instead of `9`. Presumably, TeX can skip a comment faster than ignored characters, since it doesn't have to check the catcodes of all intermediate characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LaTeX command `\verb` already implements what you are doing: every special character is assigned category code 12 so that it can be printed, except the delimiter character, which receives category code 2 (end-of-group) to end the scope of those assignments.

It does more: the space character is assigned category 13 and defined as `\`  (it won't disappear at line breaks) unless `\verb*` is called. Other characters are activated in order to break ligatures (the backquote for the Spanish ligatures, for instance).

The `comment` environment is defined by the package **verbatim** that implements the `verbatim` environment in a different way than the LaTeX kernel: it assigns catcodes like `\verb` and it reads the text line by line storing it in a macro that usually typesets its contents, but can be redefined to throw it away (this is what `comment` does). The special input `\end` followed by the name of the environment in braces stops processing.

Your code would not respect line breaks in the input and needs a terminating character. Surely it could be refined, but I would hardly consider it more efficient than the traditional methods.

Comment: One always needs a terminating character.  I said in my question how my code could be refined to use a different one and to obey line breaks.  Your first two paragraphs do answer my question as it concerns verbatim printing, but I am confused by your claim that the `verbatim` package is in any way efficient as a comment environment, since it has to read the characters one-by-one to look for `\end` (far worse than a terminating character!).  Even if you want to save the input, you can just put my two lines of code at the front of a `\vbox` in a box register.

Comment: The kernel `verbatim` does this (but using TeX's feature of delimited arguments, which is equivalent to looking for an end-of-group character); the **verbatim** package versions reads line by line and so it's much more efficient, since the `\end{verbatim}` must be at the beginning of the line.

Comment: What I'm saying is that I don't see how it can be as efficient to use TeX's macro processor to do any kind of parsing, compared to simply letting TeX's engine read input characters blindly.