# How to make a pgf default action create a different key

Tags: pgfkeys

I know very little pgf, but I'm trying to learn...so bear with me (please).

I would like to have a default action on a pgf path so that if I try to access any unknown key, without giving it a value, the result is to define a *different* key (say `id`), with the value being the name of the original key.

so that

```
\pgfkeys{/YF/hello}
```

would actually do

```
\pgfkeys{/YF/id=hello}
```

If `hello` is unknown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you are looking for the `.unknown` key handler.  It is described in Section 55.3.5 of the PGF manual (2.10 version) and there are some examples scattered throughout the TikZ and PGF code (and PGFPlots, if I remember right).  Also, most of my packages in the TeX-SX launchpad directory (and subsequently on CTAN) have examples.

If I understand your situation correctly then the following will do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34376/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfkeys{/YF/.unknown/.code={%
    \pgfkeys{/YF/id=\pgfkeyscurrentname}
  },
  /YF/id/.initial=hello,
}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeysvalueof{/YF/id}
\pgfkeys{/YF/world}
\pgfkeysvalueof{/YF/id}
\end{document}
```

This produces `hello  world`.

Comment: Two comments: first, I like using the `.style` handler for this, since you're just calling another key: `YF/.unknown/.style = {/YF/id = \pgfkeyscurrentname}`.  (since `.style` is a kind of `.code`, it's perfectly valid as a thing to define for `.unknown`).  Second, I am always unsure when that macro changes (it seems not to in a `.unknown` handler, but definitely does with other keys) so I usually expand first: `YF/.unknown/.style/.expanded = {YF/id = \pgfkeyscurrentname}`.  It seems to work for you without this, though.

Comment: @RyanReich: Good point about the expansion.  That's something to watch for with more complicated set-ups.  I hadn't thought of `.style`; my usual cases are a little more complicated as I usually want to do something a bit like the TikZ version where it tests to see if the unknown key is a colour or an arrow or a shape before passing it on to the PGF subsystem.

Comment: @Andrew: If you're talking about the example in the 2.10 manual, section 55.3.5, I think it can be rewritten using `.style`; the only thing they do besides testing keys is expand `\pgfkeyscurrentname`, and you can do that either with `.expanded` on each `.try` or by defining a key, say, `key name/.estore in = \thiskeyname` and then calling `key name = \pgfkeyscurrentname`.  I have yet to find a situation where `.code` is actually necessary, given the way handlers work.  Maybe if you want to do something complex outside the key system.

Comment: @RyanReich: No, I'm talking about the one in `tikz.code.tex`, starting with line 1252.  If you look at that you'll see that it's quite complicated as it tests for lots of things before passing it on to the PGF system.