# Can I `.search also` a path that `.search also` another path?

Tags: pgfkeys

(This is inspired by [Problem between keys, paths with two macros and pgfkeys](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306891/))

The following code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \pgfkeys{
        %/foo/.search also={/bar,/tikz},
        %/foo/.search also={/bar},
        /bar/.search also={/tikz}
    }
    \tikz\draw[/foo/.cd,fill=red]circle(1);
\end{document}
```

produces error

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '`/foo/fill`', to which
>   you passed 'red', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled
>   it.

This is not surprising, because there is nothing under `/foo`.

---

---

The following code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \pgfkeys{
        /foo/.search also={/bar,/tikz},
        %/foo/.search also={/bar},
        /bar/.search also={/tikz}
    }
    \tikz\draw[/foo/.cd,fill=red]circle(1);
\end{document}
```

produces a picture successfully

This is not surprising either, because `/foo` tries to search `fill` under `/bar` and `/tikz`, and finds that `/tikz/fill` is defined.

[image]

---

---

The following code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \pgfkeys{
        %/foo/.search also={/bar,/tikz},
        /foo/.search also={/bar},
        /bar/.search also={/tikz}
    }
    \tikz\draw[/foo/.cd,fill=red]circle(1);
\end{document}
```

surprisingly, produces no error but a naïve picture.

[image]

It seems like `/foo` asks `/bar` to find `fill` under `/tikz`, and they success (hence no error). But for some reason the style failed to apply.

---

---

Why is this happening? Can I somehow make one of these happen:

- raise an error; or
- apply the style successfully; or even better
- apply the style successfully and raise a warning?

Comment: Did you try without the `=red` part? It should give an unknown handler something error. I remember working with this at some point but don't remember what the issue was.

Comment: @percusse Yes, indeed. If I try without the `fill=` part, it raises the same error. (`I do not know the key '/handlers/.unknown/.@cmd'`) I highly suspect that it has something to do with the default treatment of Ti*k*Z that test whether an unknown key is actually a color (mixed or pure). In this sense, it is clear that `fill=red` is not a color so Ti*k*Z did not bother to test it. (This is purely guess, otherwise things just got more complicated.

Comment: It looks like something has changed since you asked the question, I get `I do not know the key '/bar/fill', to which you passed 'red', and I am going to ignore it.` The `.unknown` code installed by `.search also` seems to check only if `/bar/fill` exists but not if `/bar` would look somewhere else. It looks like you need to install your own `.unknown` code, I believe: unknown → try `/bar/<key>`, still unknown → Try `/tikz/<key>` (but for the last stime). There are `.last retry` and `\ifpgfkeyssucess` or similar.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I get weird results even with an `.unknown` handler set to try & retry the various paths. However, I can't reproduce the problem in a small enough example to post.

Comment: @cfr If I'm seeing this right, the check `\ifpgfkeysaddeddefaultpath` is toggled false when `/foo/.unknown` attempts `\pgfqkeys{/bar}{fill=red}` which makes the `/bar/.unknown` not try anything else. (Basically, that's the different between `/bar/.cd, fill=red` and `/bar/fill=red` where the latter is assumed correct and raises an error on purpose.) I don't have the patience to look why that is and where this happens and whether this is even a bug or intended but it seems easier to setup a custom `.unknown` handler …

Answer (score 2):

If I'm seeing this right, the check `\ifpgfkeysaddeddefaultpath` that is executed at the startof the `.unknown` code set up by `.search also` is toggled false when `/foo/.unknown` attempts

```
\pgfqkeys{/bar}{fill=red}
```

which makes the `/bar/.unknown` not try anything else.

(Basically, that's the different between `/bar/.cd, fill=red` and `/bar/fill=red` where the latter is assumed correct and raises an error on purpose despite a `.search also` alternative.)

I don't have the patience to look why that is and where this happens and whether this is even a bug or intended but it seems easier to setup a custom `.unknown` handler …

It just depends on how you want to handle some things.

---

Since `/tikz/.unknown` does not make the `\ifpgfkeysaddeddefaultpath` check it doesn't differentiate between `/tikz/.cd, <key>=<value>` and `/tikz/<key>=<value>`. (Internally, instead of `.cd`, oftentimes the quicker `\pgfqkeys{/tikz}{<key>=<value>}` is used but that's basically the same.)

However, sometimes a `<key>` is a style and then it depends on in which path we execute them. Doing

```
\pgfkeys{/abc/.cd, /tikz/thick}
```

will lead to an error about an unknown key `/abc/line width` since we're still in the `/abc` path (well, unless `/abc/line width` is defined, of course, than that will be used).

This leads me to an `.unknown` handler that is very close to the [manual's example](https://tikz.dev/pgfkeys#sec-87.3.6).

Unfortunately, `/tikz/.unknown` doesn't set `\pgfkeyssuccesstrue` when it finds a color, an arrow specification or a shape's name which makes it hard to figure out whether a `/tikz/<key>` was actually successfull which means the maintainer of `/foo` can't raise a proper error message without redefining `/tikz/.unknown` or doing the same spiel itself.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{
  /bar/.search also=/tikz, % this can stay, I guess
  /foo/.unknown/.code=
    \ifpgfkeysaddeddefaultpath
      \let\unknownname\pgfkeyscurrentname
      \pgfkeysalso{
        /bar/\unknownname/.try={#1}, % only try /tikz if /bar failed
        /tikz/\unknownname/.lastretry={#1}}%
        % Ugh! /tikz/.unknown doesn't set \pgfkeyssuccesstrue
        % after it handles a color, an arrow specification or a shape's name
        % then this will be annoying:
        \unless\ifpgfkeyssuccess
          \errmessage{Well, I couldn't find /foo/\unknownname={#1},
                      /bar/\unknownname={#1} and /tikz/\unknownname={#1}.
                      I don't know what you want from me.}%
        \fi
    \else % someone tried to do /foo/<unknown key>, let's fail:
      \errmessage{myPackage: /foo/\pgfkeyscurrentname\space is an unknown key.}%
    \fi
}
\tikz[radius=1]{
  \draw[/bar/.cd, fill=red] circle[];
  \draw[/bar/fill=red]      (right:1) circle[];% will always fail
  \draw[/foo/.cd, fill=red] (right:2) circle[];
  \draw[/foo/fill=red]      (right:3) circle[];% will always fail
}

\tikz{
  \draw[/bar/.cd, inner xsep=0+0] node {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}};
  \draw[/foo/.cd, ->]     (right:1) -- +(right:.5); % Ugh!
  \draw[/foo/.cd, red!50] (right:2) -- +(right:.5); % Ugh!
  \draw[/foo/.cd, circle] (right:3.5) node[draw]{}; % Ugh!
  \draw[/foo/.cd, thick]  (right:4) -- +(right:.5);% finds /tikz/thick but then
                                                   % has to try /foo/line width
                                                   % and then /bar/line width and
                                                   % then finally /tikz/line width
}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd, abc}% → unknown /tikz/abc
\pgfkeys{/bar/.cd, abc} % → unknown /tikz/abc
\pgfkeys{/foo/.cd, abc} % → unknown /foo/abc, /bar/abc, /tikz/abc
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I think my problem is actually not the one I originally thought, so I need to think about how to handle it some more. I already had custom `.unknown` handler in place, though it fails silently which is probably bad, so this example is very useful as I wasn't altogether sure the best way to trigger the message. (I modified an example from the manual, but it didn't include error handling.)