# How to skip an `\item` entirely, with no side-effects?

Tags: lists, tex-core, parsing

In Ryan Reich's great answer to my question on [onlyitems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4502/onlyitems-how-to-select-specific-items-from-an-item-list), he had LaTeX ignore an `\item` by setting it into a `box` and then not using the box, effectively discarding it:

```
...SNIP...
\renewcommand\item[1][]{%
 % The \egroup closes off any \vbox'es from the previously ignored \item.
 % The conditional \bgroup cancels it out when there aren't any.
 \itemIf\bgroup\fi\egroup
 \let\itemIf=\iffalse%\fi
 \advance\itemsSoFar by 1 %
 \onlyitemsset{utility/store tag = {}, utility/verdict/.style = {}, select/\the\itemsSoFar, #1, utility/verdict}%
 \itemIf
  \def\next{\expandafter\itemLaTeX\itemOptions}%
 \else
  % The vbox is set and then discarded, effectively ignoring an entire \item.
  % This inner \itemLaTeX is necessary to avoid a glitch when we ignore the first \item of an itemize that itself contains a nested \itemize.  Don't ask, I don't know.
  \def\next{\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup\itemLaTeX}%
 \fi
 \next
}

...SNIP...
```

This works, but has the unfortunate side-effect of advancing the appropriate LaTeX counter, which is either good or bad, depending on how one wants to use `onlyitems`.

In my case, I want `onlyitems` to literally behave as if only the included `\items` are there, so that means that the counters must not be advanced. Since the implementation is `list`-agnostic (it should work for `enumerate`, `revnum` or any other `list` of `\items` you like to define), I cannot manually set back counters (I cannot know which are the important ones), rather I need to skip the `\item` entirely, without side-effects.

Thus, to repeat the title, the question is:

> How can I skip an `\item` without any side-effect?

Comment: With sufficient industry I'll bet a form of verbatim (well, ignored) parsing would work.  Two things are necessary: first, make `\item` the termination string, and second, count `\begin...\end` pairs so that you don't comment out half of a nested itemize.  I am not feeling up to it now, though.

Comment: You're welcome, but I *have* always wanted to see if that would work.

Comment: @RyanReich: if by "it" you mean \onlyitems, the answer is **yes**. I would publish it if I thought that others might be interested. maybe I'll just keep the current version of it on that question's page....

Comment: I actually meant the "ignore `\items` by verbatim methods", but until I answered your question, I had *also* always wanted to get the `onlyitems` thing to work in general.  If you think it's good, I'll put together a package (perhaps in December).

Comment: @RyanReich: it made writing multiple resumes/publication list/list of references/list of select publications/list of etc much easier: I have one file of definitions: Resume_data.tex and many files that call up whatever sublist they happen to need. I can dice and slice however I like, but I only need to keep one list of items...it's great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
\let\stepcounter\@gobble
```

just between `\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup` and `\itemLaTeX`. This will avoid that the counter is stepped when the item is ignored (`\item` uses `\refstepcounter` internally, which in turn does `\stepcounter`).

You'll have to enclose the `\renewcommand\item[1][]{...}` between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Comment: what if someone implements a different sort of list in which internally they use `\addtocounter`?

Comment: revnumerate.sty uses both `\stepcounter` and `\addtocounter` inorder to both count how many items there are and to count-down from that number (saved in aux) to 1. your solution seems to stop the count of total items, while the count of current item continues unscathed...resulting in a correct starting number, but a jump, and then negative item numbers...

Comment: @YossiFarjoun Do also `\let\addtocounter\@gobbletwo`.

Comment: did you read the relevant part in revnum? there's a whole section, with if's setcounters etc. won't the behavior of this part will be quite unpredictable if I simply gobble these commands?

Comment: BTW: It does work...:-)

Comment: @YossiFarjoun No, I didn't read it. But if it's a correctly written package, the trick should work.