# How could I typeset odd item or even item respectively in examination paper?

Tags: exam

I want to write a tex file of an examination paper like

```
(Derivative function)
1. $3x-1$
2. $2x+1$
3. $4x^2+2x+3$
4. $7x^3-3x-6$
5. $\sin6x-7$
6. $\cos5x+2$
```

And then, I can set a logical variable `\examtype`, say, =0, typeset

```
Exam paper (A)
(Derivative function)
2. $2x+1$
4. $7x^3-3x-6$
6. $\cos5x+2$
```

otherwise, set `\examtype`=1, typeset

```
Exam paper (B)
(Derivative function)
1. $3x-1$
3. $4x^2+2x+3$
5. $\sin6x-7$
```

.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Related Question: [onlyitems? How to select specific items from an item list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4502/onlyitems-how-to-select-specific-items-from-an-item-list).

Comment: @Peter Thank you, though the answers in the link is too complicated over my need. And, I want the labels are typeset in "real" order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a version that provides a few options. It defines a `MyExam` environment which accepts two parameters: The first is the title, and the second is used to select which items you want printed.

### 1. `odd` or `even`:

You can select to print `odd` or `even` questions:

[image]

### 2. List of Questions:

You can print a specific questions either as a explicitly specified list `1,5,6` of questions, or a range of questions `1,...,5`:

[image]

Or a combination of a list and range `1,...,4,6`:

[image]

### Notes:

- I have used `newtoggle` from [the `etoolbox` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox) as I prefer that syntax versus the `\newif` syntax. But if you don't want to include an additional package it should be pretty straightforward to adapt this to use `\newif` or [some other conditional methods](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build/33577#33577)
- [The `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/) was used for
  string comparison
- The `pgf` library was used for its math capabilities and for the `\foreach` loop.

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\newlist{MyEnumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[MyEnumerate]{label={\arabic*.}}

\newcommand{\QuestionSelector}{}%
\newcounter{MyExamCounter}
\newtoggle{DisplayThisItem}%
\newcommand{\MyItem}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{MyExamCounter}%
    \global\togglefalse{DisplayThisItem}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Remainder}{mod(\arabic{MyExamCounter},2)}%
    \IfStrEqCase{\QuestionSelector}{
        {odd}{\IfEq{\Remainder}{1}{\global\toggletrue{DisplayThisItem}}{}}%
        {even}{\IfEq{\Remainder}{0}{\global\toggletrue{DisplayThisItem}}{}}%
        }[%
            \edef\ListOfItems{\QuestionSelector}%
            \foreach \x in \ListOfItems {%
                \IfEq{\x}{\arabic{MyExamCounter}}{%
                    \global\toggletrue{DisplayThisItem}%
                    \breakforeach%
                }{}%
            }%
        ]%
    \iftoggle{DisplayThisItem}{%
        \begin{MyEnumerate}[series=MyExamList]%
            \item[\arabic{MyExamCounter}.] #1%
        \end{MyEnumerate}%
    }{}%
}%

\newenvironment{MyExam}[2]{%
    \setcounter{MyExamCounter}{0}%
    \renewcommand*{\QuestionSelector}{#2}%
    \par\noindent\textbf{#1}%
}{%
}

\newcommand*{\MyListOfQuestions}{%
    \MyItem{$3x-1$}
    \MyItem{$2x+1$}
    \MyItem{$4x^2+2x+3$}
    \MyItem{$7x^3-3x-6$}
    \MyItem{$\sin6x-7$}
    \MyItem{$\cos5x+2$}
}%
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{MyExam}{Derivative function: Odd}{odd}
        \MyListOfQuestions
    \end{MyExam}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}    
    \begin{MyExam}{Derivative function: Even}{even}
        \MyListOfQuestions
    \end{MyExam}
\end{minipage}%

\bigskip
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{MyExam}{Derivative function: 1,5,6}{1,5,6}
        \MyListOfQuestions
    \end{MyExam}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}    
    \begin{MyExam}{Derivative function: 1,...,5}{1,...,5}
        \MyListOfQuestions
    \end{MyExam}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
\begin{MyExam}{Derivative function: 1,...,4,6}{1,...,4,6}
    \MyListOfQuestions
\end{MyExam}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Peter, I appreciate your generous help. And your answer is very good. There is only one question: I prefer using the orignal `\item` syntax instead of including the content of the items in double braces. It is also easy to change the sourse code. Would you have any advice on it?

Comment: @fastbamra: That is probably is not going to be as easy as it seems. See the related question I linked to as a comment to the question. BTW, you should use the full userid when using the `@` syntax -- I was only notified of this as it is a comment on my answer, otherwise I would not have seen it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not notice that. I find there is a package `tagging` can omit some items in `itemize` by choosing specific tag. Could it have some effect on it?

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the `tagging` package. However, it appears that that requires you to wrap each item within an environment (at least in the example I saw).  I think that is going to be more work than using just `\MyItem`.  Although I think that this can be down with some hacking of the code from the `enumitem` pacakge.