# Select specific items located outside a main file

Tags: lists, itemize, input

I have a data base of questions (simply individual `.tex`-files) and include some of them in a main file with the help of simple `\input` commands, in order to create an exercise. Some of those question files contain an `itemize` environment with several `\item` corresponding to different sub-questions. My goal would be to select some of those items (similarly as already [explained here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4502/onlyitems-how-to-select-specific-items-from-an-item-list)), but directly from the main file.

The structure of the main file basically looks like

```
\begin{document}
  \begin{list}
    \input question_file_1
    \input question_file_2
    \input question_file_3
  \end{list}
\end{document}
```

And a question file can be given by

```
\citem{Title of the question}%\citem is just a redefinition of an \item}

Some text at the beginning

\begin{itemize}
  \item first sub-question
  \item second sub-question
  \item third sub-question
\end{itemize}

Sometimes some text in the end
```

So now, I would like to be able to write (in the main file) something like, for instance:

```
\begin{document}
  \begin{list}
      \input{path of file 1}{1,3} %would display the first question, but only the sub-questions 1 and 3
      \input{path of file 2} %would display the whole second question
  \end{list}
\end{document}
```

I wonder if there is a way to overload my `\input` command (or define a similar one), so that it would do the job.