# Selecting a subset of questions among a long TeX file

Tags: conditionals, exam

I have a big list of questions and solutions and I want to select a subset of them to use in exams. I am using documentclass exam. See the following example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
    \question[30] this is a question I will use in this exam
         \begin{solution} solution is here \end{solution}
    \question this is another question but I will not use in this exam
         \begin{solution} its solution is here \end{solution}
    \question[20] yet another question that will be used in this exam
       \begin{solution} yet another solution is here \end{solution}
    \question this is another question it will not be in the exam
         \begin{solution} its solution is here \end{solution}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: you need to add more informations, how to select question?...

Comment: You forgot to add \end{questions} before \end{document}.

Comment: If are a Linux user and you want select groups of questions, or even a defined number of random questions within these groups, or even copies of this exam with question in random order, then  I strongly suggest that you try [AMC](http://home.gna.org/auto-qcm/).

Comment: [is this helpful in any way ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4502/onlyitems-how-to-select-specific-items-from-an-item-list)

Answer (score 1):

There will most likely be a *more* efficient way of doing this, but when I recently had to select subsets of questions, I used `newcommand` to create a `hide` command. Note that this **will** be time consuming if you have a large number of questions.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\newcommand{\hide}[1]{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
    \question[30] this is a question I will use in this exam
         \begin{solution} solution is here \end{solution}
    % Hide the next question
    \hide{%
    \question this is another question but I will not use in this exam
         \begin{solution} its solution is here \end{solution}
    }
    \question[20] yet another question that will be used in this exam
       \begin{solution} yet another solution is here \end{solution}
    % Hide the next question
    \hide{
    \question this is another question it will not be in the exam
         \begin{solution} its solution is here \end{solution}
    }
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

You will have to go through **manually** to decide which questions you want to display.

---

**Side note:** When I was doing this, my questions were rather large (long question stem and multiple subparts). As such, I put each question in a separate tex file and gave them long descriptive names, e.g. q_car_accelerating_around_a_corner.tex

Then, in a master file I could specify which questions I wanted to include in my exam. For example I could specify `\include{q_car_accelerating_around_a_corner.tex}` and it would appear in my exam. Note that I wanted page breaks in my exam - if you didn't then you would probably want `input`. More detail can be found here: 
[When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)