# How to split bibliography into "works cited" and "works not cited"?

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I need two bib-like sections: a "References" giving works explicitly cited in my text, and a "Bibliography" (or "Further reading" if you prefer) giving everything from my bibfile that didn't already appear in "References". The first is of course completely standard, but the second... I'm stumped.

Further loose constraints: I'm somewhat committed to `biblatex` and the `biblatex-apa` style. But I'll happily accept an answer not related to them if there's any chance I can adapt it.

Comment: Some possibly relevant questions from before: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222/how-do-i-break-up-a-bibliography-into-separately-numbered-sections  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/headings-inside-the-bibliography-list

Comment: After a quick look, I think both of these will be easy with the more well-known bits of biblatex. The tricky bit is the cited/not-cited distinction, which biblatex apparently solves very elegantly (see lockstep's answer below).

Answer (score 137, accepted):

One learns something new about `biblatex` every day. :-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01,B02}.

\printbibliography[category=cited]% default title for `article` class: "References"

\printbibliography[title={Further Reading},notcategory=cited]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm speechless... after seeing this, I think my New Year's resolution will be to fully convert to biblatex.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks lockstep! @Willie Wong: biblatex has just hit v1.0, so your timing is perfect ^_^ It would be my answer to the questions you linked above too.

Comment: @lockstep, How to renumber the reference of "Futher Reading"? like [1] C.Cuthor……

Comment: @PigCry: `\printbibliography[title={Further Reading},notcategory=cited,resetnumbers=true]
`

Comment: @PigCry Why would you want any reference numbers in the _Further Reading_ list if you're not referencing them in the main text?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen just make it's form consistent with the references.

Comment: Any way to have separate sorting options for the "cited" and "not cited" lists?

Comment: Is there any way to include the <key> for the Further Reading \printbibliography options?

Comment: Another reason to number the items in the *Further Reading* list is to include immediately after, or immediately before, that list commentary about these readings, with corresponding`\cite`s.

Comment: @DGarside: you could give every item one of two keys, say `main` and `supplemental` (either within a single `.bib` file or, if it's more convenient, one `.bib` file just for the items with `main` key and another just for the items with `supplemental` key). Then use `\printbibliography[keyword=main]` and `\printbibliography[keyword=supplemental]`.

Comment: How can I choose what "not-cited" entries to show? (only 20 from a total of 300 in the bib file).

Comment: How does one use this effectively with `refsection=chapter`? In my chapter-wise bibliographies, I find that a "further reading" entry that is cited using `nocite{}` in a given chapter, gets "promoted" to "References" if it is cited in a later chapter! Moreover, it appears with a repeated number, e.g. [1], [2], [2].

Comment: thanks for this elegant trick! I'm seeing strange behavior with this, though: when adding one more than 82 \cite{...}'s (and it doesn't even matter if the keys given in the cite command exist in the bib file!), my bibliography entries suddenly all get a key of [0] (both in the cited and uncited section, and no matter whether resetnumbers is true or not). Meaning I can't use this approach when citing more than 82 references. Anybody seen this or got an idea why this might happen?

Comment: This does not work, compiled using `pdflatex main.tex -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape`

Answer (score 2):

This is just a subtle difference from the @lockstep's solution, which enables you to put subtitles on each sub-list besides the main title.

```latex
% create a list of cited and uncited refereces with biblatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% biblatex
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, sorting=none, style=numeric-comp, defernumbers=true]{biblatex} % using biblatex
\addbibresource{refs.bib} % add reference file
% for each cited reference create a category named "cited"
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\begin{document}

This one is cited \cite{jiao2013characterization}.

\nocite{*}
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[category=cited,heading=subbibliography,title={Cited papers}]
\printbibliography[title={Supplementary papers},heading=subbibliography,notcategory=cited]

\end{document}
```

`refs.bib` might be something like this

```
@article{jiao2013characterization,
  title={Characterization of high-latitude ionospheric scintillation of GPS signals},
  author={Jiao, Yu and Morton, Yu T and Taylor, Steven and Pelgrum, Wouter},
  journal={Radio Science},
  volume={48},
  number={6},
  pages={698--708},
  year={2013},
  publisher={AGU}
}

@article{linty2018detection,
  title={Detection of GNSS ionospheric scintillations based on machine learning decision tree},
  author={Linty, Nicola and Farasin, Alessandro and Favenza, Alfredo and Dovis, Fabio},
  journal={IEEE Transactions on Aerospace and Electronic Systems},
  volume={55},
  number={1},
  pages={303--317},
  year={2018},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am aware the the poster asked for an answer using the `biblatex` package, but I noticed that `biblatex` does not provide accurate IEEE citations when using `\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}`. So here is the solution using the `multibib` package for those who need to use the `IEEEtran` citation style (which is used in the IEEE conference template) and achieve the same goal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multibib}

\newcites{uncited}{Bibliography}

\begin{document}

This is a sample text that cites a source \cite{sample_cited_source}.

% print all uncited sources for the Bibliography
\nociteuncited{*}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references} % file with references

\bibliographystyleuncited{IEEEtran}
\bibliographyuncited{bibliography} % file with bibliography entries

\end{document}
```