# How to list uncited .bib entries?

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to list all items in my `.bib` database which are *not* cited by a particular document, to make sure I have not overlooked citing anything that I intended to cite.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: For a solution using `biblatex`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick and dirty way to get the job done in the unix shell:

```
comm -13 <(sed -n 's/^\\bibitem{\(.*\)}/\1/p' < document.bbl | sort) \
         <(sed -n 's/^@\(.*\){\(.*\),/\2/p' < myrefs.bib | sort)
```