# Multiple bibliographies (cited references + list of publications)

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, subdividing

I am writing a `book` document in which I have to put a `bibliography`, containing all the references cited throughout the text, and a list of publications, that should appear after the bibliography, as an appendix.

The list of publications might contain entries already appearing in the `bibliography`.

The following MWE describes what I've come up with so far:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{x}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{a}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{b}
\lipsum[1-4]
\cite{goossens}
\section{c}
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter{y}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{a}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{b}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{c}
\lipsum[1-4]


% references
\makeatletter
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliotest}

\cleardoublepage

% appendices
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Publications}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{List of Publications}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{goossensdifferent}
Michel Goossens, Frank Mittlebach, and Alexander Samarin.
\newblock {\em The Latex Companion A}.
\newblock Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993.

\end{thebibliography}


\cleardoublepage

\chapter{another app}


\end{document}
```

File `bibliotest.bib` contains the following:

```
@book{goossens,
  author = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittlebach and Alexander Samarin",
  title = "The Latex Companion A",
  year = "1993",
  publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
  address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
```

The problems are two:

1. All links point to the correct destinations, except for the two links in the TOC pointing at both the bibliography and the list of publications.
2. Though the correct title appears in the TOC (`List of Publications`), the chapter is unnumbered.

## Issues using the `multibib` package

If I load `multibib`, I solve point number 1 (all links are correct), but:

1. the chapter is still unnumbered.
2. reference numbering continues after the last reference of the first bibliography.

The code of the MWE looks like this now:

```
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{pub}{List of Publications}
...
\appendix
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Publications}
\renewcommand{\refname}{List of Publications}
\bibliographystylepub{plain}
\bibliographypub{bibliotest}
\nocitepub{*}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split bibliography into "works cited" and "works not cited"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited)

Comment: Have you looked at the package [multibib](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multibib) instead of creating the two bibliographies manually?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough not really: in the second bibliography there can be entries that are already cited in the first bibliography. @uli: I have experienced some problems with `multibib`; that's why I didn't mention in the main text at first. Now I have updated the problem description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `multibib`.  I've use the `tocbibind` package to deal with the numbering of the chapters.  It's not clear from your question whether both the regular bibliography and the list of references were supposed to be numbered chapters, or just the list of publications.  I've assumed the latter, so that the Bibliography is an unnumbered chapter, and the List of Publications is a regularly numbered Appendix.  To do this I created a user command `\numbib` that toggles the `tocbibind` bib numbering boolean. This command is used before the List of References to number its chapter.

If you want *both* the Bibliography and the List of Publications to be regular numbered chapters, you don't need to use this command, but instead can just pass the option `[numbib]` to the `tocbibind` package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib} % option to reset the bib item numbering
\usepackage{tocbibind} % to have bibliographies with numbered or unnumbered chaps
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\numbib}{\@donumbibtrue} % command to number the bib
\makeatother
\begin{filecontents}{bibtest.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\newcites{pub}{List of Publications}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{x}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{a}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{b}
\lipsum[1-4]
\cite{A01,B02}
\section{c}
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter{y}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{a}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{b}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{c}
\lipsum[1-4]

% references

\phantomsection
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibtest}

\cleardoublepage
% appendices
\appendix
\numbib
\renewcommand{\refname}{List of Publications}
\numbib
\bibliographystylepub{plain}
\bibliographypub{bibtest}
\nocitepub{*}

\cleardoublepage

\chapter{another app}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. What I meant is exactly what you understood: numbering off for the references, numbering on for the publication list.

Answer (score 4):

Even though the answer to the question [mentioned by Brent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited) does not completely solve your problem, `biblatex` is the way to go. Here is an adopted version that does what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[defernums=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}


\begin{document}

\begin{refsegment}
Some text \autocite{A01,B02}.

\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment]

\end{refsegment}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={Further Reading}]

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Note that you need a relatively recent version of `biblatex` for the support of the `title={Further Reading}` option of the `\printbibliography` command.

**Edit:** The following solution is based (as your MWE) on the `book` class and also deals with the numbering of the respective TOC entries. The main difference is the usage of `\defbibheading` to define a custom heading command for your *References* and the *Full Bibliography*.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[defernums=true]{biblatex}

% Define typesetting of references heading
\defbibheading{references}[References]{% 
  \chapter{#1}% 
  \markboth{#1}{#1}%
}

% Define typesetting of bibliography heading
\defbibheading{bibliography}[Complete Bibliography]{% 
  % define as above if you want to have this numbered as well:
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
  \markboth{#1}{#1}%
}


% The filtecontent package is just used to create an example .bib-File
% automatically out of the following (for the MWE)
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

% The bibtex database to use (\bibliography{bibliotest} in your case)
\bibliography{\jobname}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{First Chapter}

% We start a new references segement
% All \cite commands of this segment contribute
% to the segment-specific bibliography
\begin{refsegment}

Some text \autocite{A01,B02}.

% print the segment-specific bibliography (using the references style 
% defined above for the heading
\printbibliography[heading=references,segment=\therefsegment]

\end{refsegment}

\nocite{*}
% print the full bibliography (using the bibliography style 
% defined above for the heading above
\printbibliography[heading=bibliography]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I ended up using the other as it required less modifications but I've tried yours and solves the problem as well.