# Using one bib file, how can I make a References chapter and a Bibliography chapter?

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

I am writing my dissertation in LaTeX. I need to include a chapter for References (entries cited in the document) as well as another chapter for the Bibliography (the rest of the entries in the `.bib` file which were not cited).

Ideally I would have just 1 `.bib` file. I came across something here:

http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/bibliographies.html

But it didn't really work.

Comment: You give a link to a whole web page, and then say "It didn't work".  It would be best if you construct a minimal example based on the the "Multiple Bibliographies" section of the page you linked to and show us what you've tried.  There are also a few good answers here already: [Multiple bibligographies: (cited references + list of publications](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36028/2693) and [How to split bibliography into "works cited" and "works not cited"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6967/2693).

Answer (score 2):

The package [multibib](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multibib) was written exactly for this purpose.

From the documentation:

[image]