# Two bibliographies?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, subdividing

I'd like to have two bibliographies in my document. The first one is the bibliography with some references from the text. I'd like to have the second bibliography just as a list output with alphadin-style without references from the text.
I'm using LYX and all my references are labeled as `\cite{...}` which works quite well with one bib. Is there a possibility to keep the references in the text without modification (`\citefirst` e.g.) and have a second bibliography which is just visible at the end of the document?

Comment: Related (resp. a duplicate if `biblatex` solutions are permitted): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited

Comment: I have no idea whether it's supported by LyX, but the `amsrefs` package might be of use.

Comment: Definitely check out the `biblatex` package. It works very well.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this earlier in the year. The most user friendly (not that is was greatly) was the [multibib](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multibib) package. Another package, which is a bit more difficult to use, but perhaps more understandable is the [bibtopic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibtopic) package.