# Print bibliography only when references are cited

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, auxiliary-files, mla-style

The root question here is *how can one print a bibliography only when there are sources to be cited?*

**BACKGROUND**
I'm working on [expanding a small package](https://github.com/vermiculus/mla13) ([originally](http://jackson13.info/mla13/Documentation.pdf) by Jackson Taylor and Becca Funke) that formats a paper according to the MLA 13 standard.  (This format is commonly used in literature-based classes.)

The package currently provides basic formatting goodies like (something that looks like) a customized `/maketitle` and the proper running header (Last `\thepage`).  I'm trying to make it a bit more functional/robust.  This includes a growing list of features:

- Natural use of `\author`
- `\date` support
- Optional title page and abstract
- *More robust bibliography handling*
- General customization of 'customizable' things, such as "Works Cited" / "References" / etc.

**MEATY BACKGROUND**
Currently, `mla13` will print the bibliography whenever you tell it to.  Since this is *always* at the end of a MLA paper, I've just used the appropriate commands to execute it at `\end{document}`.  This little bit of automation has caused a problem -- how can the references be *intelligently* printed?  That is, if there are no sources to be cited, it's a little awkward for there to be a blank page called 'Works Cited.'

**MEAT**
Using `biblatex`, is it possible to check and see if *any* source has been cited within the document?  I've taken a look at the `job.bbl` file, and it seems that if one could check to see if the string `\entry` is not found in the file, this would suffice as a switch.  I've checked into the primitives `\read` and `\readline`, but I honestly don't have much of a clue as to how to apply the information (I don't really understand it all that well, either).

Is the way I described possible, and if so, how?  Is there a better way for this to be done?

Comment: Just use bibliography categories. The `\printbibliography[category=<category name>,...]` command doesn't print anything if the category is empty and the additional options in `...` exclude the `check` and `filter` keys. Under this approach your question is duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6967/4483.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what I need though. There is content being generated by the command that is not part of `\printbibliography` at all (eg a new page). If you can give an MWE as an answer, I'll see if it works. (I'll still be trying it on my own time throughout the day though, but I've found that the presumption of 'I'm being dumb' is always a safe one.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command

```
\printbibliography[heading=<heading>,...]
```

doesn't print anything when the `bbl` file contains no entries. If it's *cited* entries in the `bbl` file you want to consider, then use a category. The command

```
\printbibliography[heading=<heading>,category=<category>,...]
```

won't print anything provided that `<category>` is empty and the additional options settings in `...` exclude `check` and `filter`. The example below considers the `article` document class. Its default `bibliography` heading doesn't issue a page break, but we can redefine it using `\defbibheading`. Default heading definitions for the standard, KOMA-script and memoir document classes can be found in `biblatex.def`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defernumbers]{biblatex}

% add every cited article to a category
% (nb: this excludes entries accessed via \nocite)
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

% define bibliography heading that issues a page break
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{%
  \clearpage
  \section*{#1}%
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Filler text.
% More filler text \parencite{companion}.
\printbibliography[heading=bibliography,title={Works cited},category=cited]
\end{document}
```

Use of `\AtEveryCitekey` prints a bibliography only for explicitly cited entries, excluding those accessed via `\nocite`. To consider all entries in the `bbl` file that would otherwise be printed use:

```
\makeatletter
\AtDataInput{\iftoggle{blx@skipbib}{}{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}}
\makeatother
```

An empty `\printbibliography` generates a warning in the log. To avoid this you can use a boolean flag to indicate citations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defernumbers]{biblatex}

\newbool{anycited}
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifbool{anycited}{}{\global\booltrue{anycited}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\printworkscited}{%
  \ifbool{anycited}{\printbibliography}{\printnothing}}
\def\printnothing[#1]{}

\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{%
  \clearpage
  \section*{#1}%
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Filler text.
% More filler text \parencite{companion}.
\printworkscited[heading=bibliography,title={Works cited}]
\end{document}
```

With this document, biber will issue a warning about no citations. There isn't much you can do about that. Hooking `\printbibliography` into `\end{document}` might seem convenient, but you are forcing a biber run onto your users. This wouldn't make much sense to me when writing an essay that doesn't use any bibliographic data. You can probably side-step some of these issues with BibTeX, at the cost of many biblatex features.

Comment: You raise a really good point about forcing the `biber` run.  I've run into similar problems myself as a user, and it frustrates me to no end... (I've also forgotten about those countless little essays in middle/high school that used MLA without refs, as well.) *sigh*

Comment: @vermiculus I'd probably just add a load-time option to the package that indicates whether or not the user intends to use bibliographic data.

Comment: Gotcha.  Probably default to not include it automatically, correct?  As to not have new users scratching heads?  (Never taken on a project like this before -- going to be fun!)

Comment: @vermiculus Up to you. Based on the option setting you can define commands differently. There are many talented package writers you can borrow from. (BTW: Sorry about all these edits. I just noticed a bad typo so I'm going to make one more...)

Comment: Don't even worry about it.  I'll have to take a look into my own `texmf` and see what'll be handy.