# Per-section cited and uncited reference list with biblatex

Tags: sectioning, biblatex, bibliographies

I'm using the example in section `3.11.3: Multiple Bibliographies` of the [Biblatex Documentation](http://mirror.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/pub/mirrors/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf). I want to combine it with [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited/6977#6977) to get per-section `cited` and `uncited` bibliographies.

It's not working, and I'm not sure why. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\addbibresource{foo.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}
Hello, World~\cite{foo}.
\printbibliography[title={My References},heading=subbibliography,category=cited]
\printbibliography[title={Future Reading},heading=subbibliography,notcategory=cited]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

The contents of `foo.bib`:

```
@techreport{foo,
    Author = {Nault, R. M.},
    Institution = {The World},
    Title = {A report on things that matter.},
    Year = {2005}}

@techreport{bar,
    Author = {Bar, A. F.},
    Institution = {Moon Ltd},
    Title = {Moon-based Research On Moon Rocks},
    Year = {2005}}
```

This is giving me the `cited` references, but not producing a `future reading` section:

[image]

How can I successfully combine the two examples to produce a per-section `cited` and `uncited` reference list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to arise because of the scope of the `refsection` environment, which does not see your `\nocite` command. Moving said command into the environment, or suppressing the environment, works for me.

Comment: When I use `refsection=chapter` to achieve this, as in the MWE here https://www.overleaf.com/read/ymwmrckxsbxb -- the "References" and "Further Reading" references aren't correct. To me, it seems that `cite` and `nocite` aren't isolated refsectionwise... Will be happy to share any further info. Thanks!

Comment: @Christoph is it possible to number arrange the alphabetically (A-Z) and number them sequentially ? Like cited from 1- m and uncited from n+1 to m