# Does there exist a quick hack to see which bibtex sources I've used?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I have 42 sources in my bibtex (.bib file) but only 31 in my bibiliography. Is there a quick hack to find which ones I still need to write about?

Thanks

Comment: Also, for `biblatex`: [How to split bibliography into "works cited" and "works not cited"?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/6977#6977)

Comment: Could you confirm if @TorbjørnT.'s links have resolved the issue- we could then close this as a duplicate if you agree :)

Comment: Or, if this question would be different, perhaps edit it, notify us to reopen it.

Comment: The solution give on that other page did not work, but it could be something trivial. 

on the MWE for refcheck solution, I get a File 'refcheck.sty' not found. I get the same error when trying to use it in my larger document. Any suggestions?

Comment: could be time for an update: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)