# Obtaining a specific order for references of an annotated bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, custom-bib

We are currently writing an annotated bibliography and cannot get the ordering of references as we want. In the bibliography we have two kinds of entries:

- annotated entries (the ones that the document talks about).
- normal references (referenced by the annotated entries).

The document contains some text (with some `\cite{}` commands) and then, at the end, there are two sections:

- the list of annotated entries plus annotations. The order of this list is not auto generated, the list is created by us. Each entry is obtained with the `\bibentry{}` command.
- the list of normal references. This would be nice if it was auto-generated.

We would like the citation format to be numerical.
Moreover, the number should be the order in which the entries appear in the two sections at the end of the document, as in the following example:

> **Title**
>
> blablabla [2] blablabla [3] blabla [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited/6977#6977)
>
> **Annotated References**
>
> [1] auth, title
>     Annotation
>
> [2] auth, title
>     Annotation
>
> **References**
>
> [3] auth, title

We have not found the bibliography style that we need for this, so we are asking you if you either know about such a style (which we clearly missed) or if you can help us crafting the code that will give us the bibliography in that order.

We've seen some [related questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited/6977#6977) but we were unable to make them work for this case.