# How to redefine the key of a bibliography entry?

Tags: bibtex, natbib, bibentry, alias

I've posed [a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132749/obtaining-a-specific-order-for-references-of-an-annotated-bibliography) but it has received no answer, so i'll try with a different specification.

We are manually defining the order of the bibliography and we want this custom order to be reflected in the numerical key set up by bibtex.

For example, we want the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib} 
@misc{A01,
  shorthand = {Author},
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\title{A title}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nobibliography{mybib}

I cite number two~\cite{B02} and then number three~\cite{C03} and finally number one~\cite{A01}
%i now show the bibliography with number three, one and two
\noindent\cite{C03}~\bibentry{C03}

\noindent\cite{A01}~\bibentry{A01}

\noindent\cite{B02}~\bibentry{B02}

\end{document}
```

To output this (with due changes somewhere):

```
 I cite number two [3] and then number three [1] and finally number one [2]
 [1] C. Cuthor. Charlie, 2002 
 [2] A. Author. Alpha, 2001 
 [3] B. Buthor. Bravo, 2002
```

but of course we get this:

```
 I cite number two [2] and then number three [3] and finally number one [1]
 [3] C. Cuthor. Charlie, 2002 
 [1] A. Author. Alpha, 2001
 [2] B. Buthor. Bravo, 2002
```

So the Key (if that's the name of the number between square brackets) is decided by the style and not by us, and we want to modify it to our liking.

We've tried with aliases but their scope is local, and i can't make it global.

Any tool that will make this work is more than welcome, we are not fixed to specifics such as natbib.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you restricted to `bibtex` and `natbib` or could you also use `biblatex` and `biber`? Note: I’m not sure how or whether this pair can do it (but it’s more likely).

Comment: So you just want a way to decide the order of bibliography with natbib ?

Comment: I'm confused by your requested output you say you want `I cite number two~\cite{B02}` to make `I cite number two [2]`  but `B02` is `Bravo` but you want the list to show `[2]` as `Alpha` ???

Comment: @Crissov, i've edited the question: we're open to anything that will produce the desired output.

Comment: @ppr, basically yes

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for the correction, i've edited the example!

Answer (score 2):

If it is ok for you to sort the references in your bib-file, you could do the following.

1. Sort references in bib-file.
2. Use `\nocite{*}` at the beginning of your document.
3. Generate your bibliography with `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` and `\bibliography{mybib}`.

Here the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[square,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib} 
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Charlie},
}
@misc{A01,
  shorthand = {Author},
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\title{A title}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

I cite number two~\cite{B02} and then number three~\cite{C03} and finally number one~\cite{A01}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

You get this:

[image]

Comment: Well, this is something we hadn't seen.
I guess it's a start, but i'll wait with marking this as the answer, because i would really like to see how to hand-pick the square-bracketed value!