# biblatex: Retrieve which references are NOT used

Tags: biblatex

I think this is a gerenal issue: If you have a `.bib`-file with 200 entries and you use maybe about 170 of it, how can you retrieve the missing 30 keys?

The background is: `\nocite{*}` will add all references, but that's not what I want. I want only the references which are really used. **But**: I also want to know what keys are not used, so I can scan through that list and check if important references are missing.

Comment: Thank you for your question! Still, a small example of fully compilable TeX code and a bib file would be a great starting point for the solvers, otherwise they must prepare it by themselves anyway and it costs precious time.

Comment: Take a look at this great answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6977/6908

Comment: yes that already answers my question. thx a lot