# How can I make the split bibliographies work?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am using Windows 8 64 bit, TeXStudio and MiKTeX, and I am trying to implement the following code in my work:

[How to split bibliography into "works cited" and "works not cited"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited)

Now, `biblatex` works just fine and everything, but I am having some trouble splitting my references in a cited and a non-cited part.

My problem is the following: Let's say I have two items in my bibliography. When I cite the first item, it shows up in the references part, but the second item does *not* show up in the “further reading” part. Now when I cite the second item and compile, it does show up in the References part. When I then remove the citation of the second item in the document, and then compile *twice*, it does show up in the further reading cathegory.
Summary:

```
\cite{article1}
```

**References**
article1

**Further readings**
*empty*

After that:

```
\cite{article1}
\cite{article2}
```

**References**
article1
article2

**Further readings**
*empty*

Then:

```
\cite{article1}
%\cite{article2}
```

and compile two times:

**References**
article1

**Further readings**
article2

Isn't it strange? Of course I would like if I wouldn't have to go through this procedure, as I have a bibliography of more than 40 items, still growing. I should be able to compile the last configuration directly, and that then article 2 would show up directly under Further readings. ;)

I am using:

```
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}


\begin{document}

\printbibliography[category=cited]

\printbibliography[title={Further reading},notcategory=cited,resetnumbers=true]

\end{document}
```

What I think might be the problem, is that `\AtEveryCitekey` and `\thefield` are marked as unrecognized commands in TeXStudio.

Do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: TeXstudio is only an editor. Therefore it does not recognize every command which can be loaded through some LaTeX package. Only the most common ones are build in.

Comment: I was just generating a MWE, when i recognized that i had forgotten to put the following command: \nocite{*}.

I think that this is the problem, but now i am getting the error message: Emergency stop. No "backend" specified, using Biber backend.

Comment: Which i just now could resolve. It seems to work now!

Sorry, for your time, it really only was this line missing, so i think the reason why i had to go through this complicated procedure is because by default, latex doesn't put the items of the bibliography as non-cited items.

Comment: @user50573: Well, in this case it still provided the solution ;-)

Comment: Jep. Schönen tag noch! ;)

Comment: @user50573: Schönes Restwochenende ;-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem arising when not using the necessary commands (see comments above) that has since been resolved.