# How to get a Reference section and a Bibliography

Tags: natbib, subdividing

I am currently using a custom class (`mqthesis.cls`) to author my thesis. It works very well but it only gives a references section and I want to have a references section (with only the actually cited entries) as well as a bibliography (with all background reading listed).

I know I can use `\nocite{*}`to make it so that the reference section actually includes my full bibliography but this only gives me a hybrid single section that contains my bibliography and citation links. I need two sections.

I can include the \bibliography action twice but that just gets me two duplicate sections (both called 'references' as the `.cls` file stipulates).

How do I get two distinct sections? Is it by editing the `.cls,` the `.tex` or both?

Edit: I am using `natbib` package currently.

Comment: If (!) you're willing to switch from `natbib` to `biblatex`, here's a solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited

Comment: Thanks Lockstep. As a total amateur I am nervous at the extent of change that might bring. I'll look into biblatex.

Am I to infer that there is no way of doing it in natbib?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a try with `multibib`. This works with `natbib`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[numbers,square,sort]{natbib}
%%------------------------------------------------------------------
%% bibliography with mutiple entries
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
%%------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcites{biblio}{Bibliography}
%%------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{one.bib}
@Article{oneart,
  author =   {Author, O.},
  title =    {Title One},
  journal =  {One J.},
  year =     2010
}
@Article{twoart,
  author =   {Author, M.},
  title =    {Title Two},
  journal =  {Two J.},
  year =     2014
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
%%------------------------------------------------------------------
\citep{oneart}
\nocitebiblio{twoart}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{one}
%%------------------------------------------------------------------
%%\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}   %% you may need this
\bibliographystylebiblio{plainnat}
\bibliographybiblio{one}
%%------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]