# Get a list of uncited entries in a BibTeX file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

Suppose I have a rather large BibTeX bibliography file that contains both works cited in a paper as well as works I saved to my bibliography without actually citing them in my paper.

Is there a way to **only** print those entries that are *not yet cited in the paper*, say, as a reminder that I wanted to include them at some point in my thesis?

This might seem somewhat counter-intuitive, but it has to do with the fact that I use an external tool for library management that creates a BibTeX file with all the saved entries, regardless of whether they are actually cited in my paper.

I'm using `biblatex` and the `biber` backend to create my bibliography.

Comment: You can use [`bibtool`](http://www.gerd-neugebauer.de/software/TeX/BibTool/index.en.html) to extract the entries that have been cited, and use [`bibcut`](http://www.development.root-1.de/Bibcut_wiki.php) to compare that to your main library.

Comment: You may also like this entry: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212515/how-to-get-uncited-items-printed-in-a-different-color

Comment: @darthbith Thanks for the input. Bibcut seems to have some trouble with entries containing a "shorttitle" tag or similar, however, apparently confusing the two entries and marking them as different.

Comment: @barghest Hmm too bad it didn't work... I have never tried it myself, but I think you have a pretty good answer already! :-)

Comment: Another approach linked for completeness' sake: [see this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6977/27591).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To print a list of references that have not been cited you can create a `check` that filters out the cited one (you have to enable the `citetracker` feature, e.g., `\usepackage[citetracker=true]{biblatex}`).

The `check` can be created as follows

```
\defbibcheck{uncited}{
  \ifciteseen
    {\skipentry}
    {}
}
```

and then put a `\nocite{*}` in the document, and use

```
\printbiblipgraphy[check=uncited]
```

PS I think this has been asked before, but I was not able to locate it.

Comment: A similar technique has been used in [\nocite{*} for single bibdatasources with biblatex/biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170316/35864).

Comment: somehow I can't get this to work, the printbibliography[check=uncited] still picks up many that are actually cited somewhere; I have enabled citetracker; I have cleared the intermediate files; what else could I be doing wrong?