# How to create both a reference list (for items cited) and a bibliography (for additional reading/items not cited) using BibTex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am currently writing my PhD thesis using the {report} class on Texshop (LaTex) for Mac. I have used BibTex to compile my reference list, in which I have created a library called 'database' which has in it all of the texts that I have read.

Using the command:

```
\bibliography{database}
```

in the preamble, I can generate a bibliography of the references that I have cited within the text.

OR

using the command:

```
\nocite{database}
```

in the preamble, I can generate a bibliography of all of the references I have compiled in my library (including cited references and additional reading).

How do I get two distinct sections, one for cited references and one for additional reading?

Comment: Would you consider using `biblatex`? It will be easier.

Comment: Yes, I would if it is easier/better. I'm a bit of a novice though I'm afraid: could you offer some advice?

Comment: It already has been asked in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited/6977#6977) and has an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that there are better ways to go. However, here is a rather convoluted way to do it within the constraints given by the OP.

Assuming your document is named `document.tex`, your citations are in `database.bib`, and that you want all of the references in `database.bib` that are not explicitly cited to be in Additional Reading:

**1. Compile your document as is**

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}
Some text \cite{Acevedo12}.
\bibliography{database}
\end{document}
```

This results in the  `document.aux`  file containing `\citation{key}` entries for each of the citations. In this case it contains an entry `\citation{Acevedo12}`.

**2. Run `BibTex`**

This creates the  `document.bbl` file which is the formatted references section. The `\bibliography` command is akin to `\input{document.bbl}` and will be used as such below.

**3. Rename `document.bbl` to `cited.bbl`**

This will save the formatted bibliography for the cited references.

**4. Add `\nocite{*}` and recompile your document**

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}
Some text \cite{Acevedo12}.
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{database}
\end{document}
```

This results in the `document.aux` file containing the `\citation{*}` command, which will instruct `BibTex` to include all of the references in the library.

**5. Run `BibTex`**

This creates a new `document.bbl` file containing all of the references in the library formatted for the references section.

**6. Create a new `.tex` document (assumed to be called `addreading.tex`) with the following and compile**

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatletter
    \newcounter{citedrefcount}%
    \newcommand\setcited[2]{\expandafter\gdef\csname citedref#1\endcsname{#2}}
    \newcommand\addcited[1]{\stepcounter{citedrefcount}\setcited{\thecitedrefcount}{#1}}%
    \newcommand\getcited[1]{\csuse{citedref#1}}%

    \newcommand\adduncited[1]{%only add if the reference key is not contained within the cited references
        \newcount\temp\aloop\temp=1 step 1 until {\thecitedrefcount} do {%
            \gdef\uncited{\cite{#1}}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\getcited{\@arabic\temp}}{#1}}%compare the citation key to the \temp citedref key
            {%citekey matches a citedref. redefine \uncited to do nothing and end the loop
                \gdef\uncited{\relax}%
                \temp=\thecitedrefcount}%
            {%citekey does not match checked citedref. do nothing (keep definition of \uncited)
            }} \endaloop\temp
        \uncited%execute \uncited (does nothing if reference is already in the cited list, cites the reference if it is not citedyet).
        }
\makeatother


%%% Basic Loop
%Taken from David Salomon's The Advanced TeXbook pg 191
\def\aloop#1=#2 {%
    \long\def\next step ##1 until ##2 do ##3 \endaloop#1{%
        ##3%
        \advance#1 by ##1
        \ifnum#1>##2\relax\else\next step ##1 until ##2 do ##3 \endaloop#1 \fi%
        }%end of \next
    #1=#2 \next}%end of \aloop  

\begin{document}
    \def\bibitem#1{\addcited{#1}}
    \input{cited.bbl}
    \def\bibitem#1{\adduncited{#1}}
    \input{document.bbl}
    \bibliography{database}
\end{document}
```

This compares the citation keys in the `document.bbl` file to those in the `cited.bbl` file, adding `\citation{key}` to the `addreading.aux` file only for citation keys not in the `cited.bbl` (i.e., not cited in the original document).

**7. Run `BibTex` on the addreading file.**

This results in `addreading.bbl`, which is the formatted references section for the references not cited in the original document.

**8. Finally, modify the original document to reference the two .bbl files**

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}
Some text \cite{Acevedo12}.
\input{cited.bbl}
\renewcommand\refname{Additional Reading}
\input{addreading.bbl}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

Redefining `the bibliography` environment to account for maximum number of references in either of the references sections allows for the enumeration to continue and the alignment to be correct after a couple runs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{allcitations}%counter to hold the total number of citations
\gdef\maxsubcitations{0}%maximum number of citations in a citation list (determines the space necessary for the enumeration
\makeatletter
    \let\oldthebib\thebibliography
    \let\oldendthebib\endthebibliography
    \renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%redefine thebibliography environment to have a running count and align based on the largest number of citations
            \oldthebib{\maxsubcitations}%
            \ifthenelse{#1>\maxsubcitations}%
            {%
                \gdef\maxsubcitations{#1}
                \immediate\write\@auxout{\noexpand\gdef\noexpand\maxsubcitations{#1}}
            }{}
            \addtocounter{\@listctr}{\theallcitations}
        }{%
            \addtocounter{allcitations}{\c@enumiv}
            \oldendthebib}
\makeatother    
\begin{document}
Some text \cite{Acevedo12}.
\input{cited.bbl}
\renewcommand\refname{Additional Reading}
\input{addreading.bbl}
\end{document}
```

[image: Partial page]