# Bibliography is not Printed Using Tex Studio

Tags: bibliographies

This is a question from the answer given in the [question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited/6977#6977)
I used the following codes given there,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01,B02}.\cite{A01,B02}

\printbibliography[category=cited]% default title for `article` class: "References"

\printbibliography[title={Further Reading},notcategory=cited]

\end{document}
```

But while I am running, it is giving this output, not like whatever given in that answer.

[image]

Questions:

- And one more important thing, it is not listing the reference items. Means I could not find the Reference in my article at last page.
- In citation, it is not giving the numerical values, whereas it is giving the keys. I want the numerical values like `[1]`, `[2]`, etc.

What is the problem? Help me

Technical Details:

- I am using Linux mint and Texstudio to compile this...

Comment: As Jerome mentions in his answer, you need to run `biber` between runs of `pdflatex`, have you done so?

Comment: See also [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875) for more information about the general problem, and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154754) for some info on configuring TeXstudio.

Comment: I voted to close because of lack of feedback and the fact that your example works just fine, so I assume it has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the compiler you use ?

Your problem comes from the compilation.
I have no problem using TeXstudio and latexmk.
There is no problem using an online compiler ([example](https://www.overleaf.com)).

Using a terminal, I was able to have a correct pdf using :

```
pdflatex test.tex
biber test
pdflatex test.tex
pdflatex test.tex
```