# Split cited and non-cited in biblatex-chicago bibliography with crossreference

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I am trying to produce a bibligraphy where non-cited items in the `.bib` file are listed below cited references. For most purposes, the solution provided at [How to split bibliography into "works cited" and "works not cited"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited) works fine.

However, in certain cases (apparently when I have an item crossref-ed to an enclosing item), I get the error `Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...xt@context }{\abx@field@localnumber`; I have tried deleting all auxiliary files as suggested in `biblatex` documentation to no avail.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[defernumbers=true,annotation,backend=biber,notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@collection{author:main,
  location = {Somewhere},
  title = {Collection Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  editor = {The Editor},
  date = {9999}
}

@incollection{author:item,
  author = {The Author},
  title = {Item Title},
  pages = {999},
  crossref = {author:main}
}

@book{uncited:book,
  location = {Elsewhere},
  title = {Book Title},
  publisher = {Other Publisher},
  author = {Uncited Author},
  date = {9999}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{author:item}.

\printbibliography[category=cited]% default title for `article` class: "References"

\printbibliography[title={Further Reading},notcategory=cited]

\end{document}
```

I understand that `defernumbers` adds complexity so I'm certainly open to an alternative approach to producing the uncited listing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a non-numeric style, such as all members of the `biblatex-chicago` family, `defernumbers` makes no difference.

Your MWE works just fine if you simply drop the option `defernumbers=true`.

Even though we can solve the problem easily by not using `defernumbers` here, I believe this is a problem in `biblatex` and have reported the issue ([#568](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/568)).

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought that somehow we were taking advantage of some side-effect so it never occurred to me to remove that option. But I think you are right; with a different style the problem would remain.

Comment: @K.G.Feuerherm `defernumbers` is often needed with `numeric` styles, but has no effect for non-`numeric` styles. It is quite a specific combination of things that comes together to create this bug. I was not able to reproduce it in a simpler setting. But still ... it's annoying.