# Print list of non-cited bibliography entries without citation keys

Tags: biblatex, citing, chapters, biber

I am using `biblatex` with the added feature of adding all cited references to their own category:

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
```

as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366106/split-cited-and-non-cited-in-biblatex-chicago-bibliography-with-crossreference). Now consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[refsegment=chapter]{biblatex}
    \DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}%so we can access all non-cited as own category
    \AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\begin{filecontents}{thebib.bib}
@misc{mathworks_constant_2018,
    type = {Documentation},
    title = {Constant volume pneumatic chamber based on ideal gas law},
    url = {https://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ref/constantvolumepneumaticchamber.html},
    urldate = {2022-01-01},
    journal = {Mathworks Simulink Documentation},
    author = {{Mathworks}},
    year = {2018},
}
@online{WinNT,
  author = {MultiMedia LLC},
  title = {{MS Windows NT} Kernel Description},
  year = 1999,
  url = {http://web.archive.org/web/20080207010024/http://www.808multimedia.com/winnt/kernel.htm},
  urldate = {2010-09-30}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{thebib.bib}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{This is a chapter}
    \autocite{mathworks_constant_2018}
    \endrefsegment%anything after not in any segment -> not printed by bibbysegment
    \nocite{*}%
    \printbibheading%print big heading once
    \defbibheading{subbibliography}{\vspace*{1.5\baselineskip}\section*{\Cref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}}}%
    \bibbysegment[heading=subbibliography]%cycle through all segments and print
    \defbibheading{notcited}{\section*{Further Reading}}
    \printbibliography[notcategory=cited, heading=notcited]
\end{document}
```

with an example inspired in parts by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3608/120853).

The `\defbibheading` with `cleveref` is a redefinition to allow clickable links. It is not part of the example, but I left it in so nothings breaks. I left `hyperref` out so they don't show. The result is:

[image]

**Is there a way to remove citation keys – in this case `[1]` – from the *Further Reading* section?**

Since no entries there are cited anywhere, we do not need citation keys there. It is just meant as a list for anyone who cares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a new bibliography environment for the *further reading* section. I just copied the definition from `authoryear.bbx` as that gives a reasonably pleasant result. You will also want to use the option `defernumbers` to make sure that the numbering comes out as expected (you could also add the option `omitnumbers` to the `\printbibliography` command of the *further reading* section, though that would not change the output here; there would only be a difference if *further reading* is followed by another numbered `\printbibliography` with entries that have not appeared before).

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[refsegment=chapter, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\defbibheading{subbibliography}{%
  \section*{\Cref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}}}

\defbibheading{notcited}{\section*{Further Reading}}

\defbibenvironment{bibnonum}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{mathworks_constant_2018,
  type    = {Documentation},
  title   = {Constant volume pneumatic chamber based on ideal gas law},
  url     = {https://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ref/constantvolumepneumaticchamber.html},
  urldate = {2022-01-01},
  journal = {Mathworks Simulink Documentation},
  author  = {{Mathworks}},
  year    = {2018},
}
@online{WinNT,
  author  = {MultiMedia LLC},
  title   = {{MS Windows NT} Kernel Description},
  year    = 1999,
  url     = {http://web.archive.org/web/20080207010024/http://www.808multimedia.com/winnt/kernel.htm},
  urldate = {2010-09-30}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{This is a chapter}
  \autocite{mathworks_constant_2018}

  \endrefsegment
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibheading
  \bibbysegment[heading=subbibliography]
  \printbibliography[notcategory=cited, env=bibnonum, heading=notcited]
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography for Chapter 1 with numbers. Further reading without numbers.]

I had to use `report` instead of `scrreprt` because of https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/857 to make the MWE work for me. I also removed the `\vspace*{1.5\baselineskip}%` for the MWE as I wanted to avoid the excessive space it introduces with the standard class.

Comment: This is very nice, thank you. The indentation for the second line is very nice and important for legibility. I do not have to use `defernumbers`, because I am not on a numeric style for the real document. Thank you for the tip. Further, I could run `scrreprt` successfully. Note that I am using `refsegment=chapter`, not `refsection=chapter`. Removing `\vspace` is a good touch I had overlooked but now adopted.

Comment: @HansLollo For non-`numeric` styles the `defernumbers` is indeed not relevant or necessary. You are probably using an older version of `biblatex` or KOMA script if you don't get the undesirable behaviour (so my advise is: Don't update your system right now!), it is structurally the same issue for the `refsegment` and `refsection` option.