# Create a biblatex bibliography of all entries without citations

Tags: biblatex

This question is sort-of the opposite of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17128/using-bibtex-to-make-a-list-of-references-without-having-citations-in-the-body-of) FAQ.

I am having a .bib file with all the literature I've consulted for my project. Currently (until I have a solution) I use `\nocite{*}` to print the whole bibliography (using `biblatex` with `biber`). But what I *want* to have is two separate bibliographies: first the regular one with all cited entries and then another one (labeled "further literature") that includes all entries from the .bib file for which there is *no* citation.

Of course I could use a keyword (e.g. `further-literature`) and do something like `\nocite{*} \printbibliography[keyword={further-literature}]`. But I definitely don't want to maintain that list of uncited works manually! That's not how that should be done.

So is there a filter in `biblatex` that allows to print entries without citations but *no* entries that *do* have a citation?

Comment: You can setup a category cited. See e.g https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477523/print-list-of-non-cited-bibliography-entries-without-citation-keys (there are more answers with similar ideas)

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6967/35864 help?

Answer (score 0):

Both links in the comments by Ulrike Fischer and moewe exactly answer my question.

I don't know why I didn't find them (I *did* try searching before asking ...), but I suggest marking my question as duplicate.

Comment: It's always easier to find the answer if you know it already...