# Biblatex visual distinction between categories

Tags: biblatex

Following scenario (many questions about it on the site): I have a bibliography that contains items I cite and some items I do not cite. As I wish to keep the sort order in my bibliography I do not want to have to different sections as answered before: [How to split bibliography into "works cited" and "works not cited"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited) (MWE sort of copied from there)

What I'm trying to achieve is the following: I want `\printbibliography` to print the whole entry text and key in grey if the item is not cited within the document. That means if the entry is not in category `cited` the items shall print differently.

Note: I use a more complex setup for the bibliography in my main document, so changing every single field to print different for different categories should be avoided.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
Some text \autocite{A01,B02}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a combination of `ifcategory`, `DeclareFieldFormat`, and `AtEveryBibitem` will do it for you.

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\pagestyle{empty}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifcategory{cited}{}{\color{black!50}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{%
  \ifcategory{cited}{}{\color{black!50}}\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
Some text \autocite{A01,B02}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great thing. Small improvement: You should use `\mkbibbrackets` instead of hardcoded `[` and could use `\ifcategory{cited}{}{\color{black!50}}\mkbibbrackets{#1}` in `labelnumberwidth`.

Comment: True, I'll modify it.