# Print bibliography by categories with different colors

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sorting

I have a long document (my lab notebook) in which the bibliography is sorted into topical categories. I'd like to either

1. Show items that I've read already in a different color, within their topical categories, or
2. Sort the "already read" items into a different category and print that with a different color.

I know how to do this by brute force. For example,

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{Cat1}
\defbibheading{Cat1}{\section*{Cat1}}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{Cat2}
\defbibheading{Cat2}{\section*{Cat2}}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{Read}
\defbibheading{Read}{\section*{Read}}
```

and then

```
\bibbycategory
```

I get a bibliography by category, but I can't figure out how to make "Read" items a different color.

Alternatively, I can do

```
\printbibliography[category=Cat1]
\printbibliography[category=Cat2]
{\color{blue}
  \printbibliography[category=Read]}
```

but then I have to list all the categories, and since these are topical areas in my research, the list of categories can become long and I lose the advantage of automating the process.

Ideal would be something along the lines of

```
\bibbycategory[notcategory=Read]
 {\color{blue}
  \printbibliography[category=Read]}
```

But of course there's no such option to \bibbycategory and I can't figure out how to do something that simple. Any suggestions?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[nobib, sfsidenotes]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%
\usepackage[natbib, authordate, ibidtracker=false, backend=biber,
   doi=false, url=false, arxiv=false, isbn=false, eprint=false, autocite=inline, backref=true]{biblatex-chicago}
%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
@book{fictional01,
    author    = "Donald Trump",
    title     = "A huge book, the best book",
    year      = "2001",
    publisher = "The Trump Organization",
    address   = "New York, NY"
}
\end{filecontents*}
%
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
%
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{Cat1}
\defbibheading{Cat1}{\section*{Cat1}}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{Cat2}
\defbibheading{Cat2}{\section*{Cat2}}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{Read}
\defbibheading{Read}{\section*{Read}}
%
\newcommand{\addcite}[2]{%
    {\color{blue}\fullcite{#2}}\addtocategory{#1}{#2}
}
\newcommand{\donecite}[2]{%
    {\color{ProcessBlue}\fullcite{#2}}\addtocategory{Read}{#2}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

Blah, blah, blah

Things I need to read in the next hour:
\begin{itemize}
    %\item \addcite{Cat1}{greenwade93}
    % change \addcite{} to \donecite{} when I've read it
    \item This is important: \donecite{Cat1}{greenwade93}
    \item This is even more important: \addcite{Cat2}{goossens93}
    \item People tell me to read this: \addcite{Cat1}{fictional01}
\end{itemize}
%
%
\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]
%
\bibbycategory
%
%\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]
%\printbibliography[notcategory=Read]
%
%{\color{blue}
%\printbibliography[category=Read, heading=Read]
%}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please add two or three of your bib entrys to your question and a compilable code showing how you build your bibliography so far?

Comment: A suggestion (not tested), based on `pgffor`:  `\foreach \cat in\{Cat1,Cat2,...\}{\printbibliography[category=\cat]}` should do the same as `\bibbycategory`, excluding the `Read` category if it's not in the list.

Comment: Added an MWE above.

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380845/biblatex-visual-distinction-between-categories/380850#380850

Comment: Do you want to colour them *only* in the Read bibliography, or there and wherever they appear in all category bibliographies? If the later, then my answer to the above question will do what you want.

Comment: If you want just the Read bibliography coloured, then can't you just do `\defbibheading{read}{\color{blue}\section*{Read}}`?

Comment: Bingo! That works (that is, the \defbibheading suggestion). Only thing I had to change was that "read" needs to be "Read" in both places. But it works! Thanks very much!

Comment: Make that an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can colour the whole *Read* bibliography by setting the colour in `\defbibheading`:

```
\defbibheading{Read}{\color{blue}\section*{Read}}
```