# Inverse bibliography: Print all works that aren't cited

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

Assume that I have a large bibliography file and a large document with a lot of citations. Now I want to know which works collected in the bibliography file aren't cited in my document.

Is there a way to achieve this?

P.S. I am aware of a recent article in *Die TeXnische Kommödie* where a partial solution of this problem is presented (basically, use an unsorted bibliography, use a sentinel for the last citation, and use \nocite{*}—all bibliography entries coming after the sentinel are not cited). There must be something better than that.

Comment: After writing up my question, the stackexchange engine revealed this question and answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited which is maybe close enough to count as a duplicate. I'll let my question stand here for enlarging the search engine surface.