# print only cited entries after using \nocite{*}

Tags: biblatex

In my document i have to print all my bib entries, to present the result of my research for the the chosen topic...  therefore i am using:

```
% Biblatex
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
citestyle=authoryear-ibid,
url=false,
isbn=false,
notetype=footonly,
hyperref=false,
sortlocale=de]{biblatex}

% print all bib entries
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```

The Problem is that i want to print the bib entries at the and of the document again. But this time only the cited ones... therefore i am using:

```
% print only cited entries
\printbibliography
```

The setting \nocite{*} is still active and all bib entries are printed again. How can i deactive the setting at the end of the document to print cited bib entries only?

Comment: You can use a `refsection` around `\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none]`

Comment: `\begin{refsection}\nocite{*}\printbibliography[heading=none]\end{refsection}` might work, but it would be *much* easier to help you if you could show us a so called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that shows us what you have so far.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have issued `\nocite{*}` all entries will end up in the bibliography unless you apply additional filtering, there is no going back.

With the nice trick explained in [How to split bibliography into "works cited" and "works not cited"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6967/35864) you can split your bibliography into 'cited' and 'uncited' works. This would allow you to sort of 'turn off' `\nocite{*}` again.

Using `refsection`s, however, you can create a separate list that is independent of the rest of the document. This is usually very suitable for a list of publications if all entries that are explicitly cited are to appear in the normal bibliography at the end.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{worman}
\begin{refsection}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword=secondary, title={List of Publications}]
\end{refsection}
\cite{sigfridsson,nussbaum}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The MWE shows to bibliography lists, one "List of Publications" and one "References". The "References" contain only the three works cited in the document, the "List of Publications" shows five entries]