# Tracking reference that are not cited

Tags: bibliographies, editors

I am a beginner using winedt 10 as editor and Biber as backend. I have picked a lot of references in my bib file. When I finished my citation, I found a great mismatch between the number of entries in bib file and the number of entries in the bibliography of the generated pdf. So obviously I did not cite all the references.
Please tell me if there is any method available in WinEdt (or Texwork) to identify the cited (or uncited) references from the bib file available in the left panel under the document tree ? Or possibly configure the auto- suggest to show only the uncited references?

Comment: hm, well if you didn't cited them, then perhaps it wasn't needed to cite them? But beside this: you can add everything with \nocite{*} and then split into cited and not cited works: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: You are right but in some (most) undergraduate books there is no citation inside the book but there is a bibliography list in last page.

Comment: I can see the list of available references from the tree in WinEdt and can manually compare them with the generated PDF. I am looking something similar to MS word reference manager (XML) where it ticks the references that are cited.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the link, I can now atleast separate them statically by printing them in two categories using the code. However an automated process that can take care of the issue would always be better.