# Creating a seperate reference section with all non-cited Literature

Tags: biblatex

I want to create a regular reference section with all the literature I cited in my document but also a separate one with a custom title (uncited literature) where All the keys should be listed that I haven't cited.

Is there a (simple) way to do that?

Comment: You might want to try this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6967/164672

Comment: `\nocite{*}` is probably you are looking for.