# unused bibliography articles

Tags: biblatex

I have many citations in biliography file that I am not using them in the text.

To be more specific, I have a file with name bibliography.bib and contains

```
@article{first, title={...}, etc}
@book{second, title={.....}, etc}
```

and so on. However, I am not using all of them in my document. Is there any way to identifying the references that I am not using and remove them? I am using overleaf if that's helpful!

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community hope that this is better!

Comment: WinEdt has a nice macro to generate a minimal `bib` file from the `bbl`  file

Comment: Why exactly are you worried about unused references? They will not show up your file, after all. That said, I am not aware of a fully automatic method to remove such entries.

Comment: Last tab of a reference in Jabref  show if  it is  cited in one or more latex files in the directory. If no cites are found, you can delete the reference. However, I would do first a backup of the  whole .bib file, just in case that you remove some reference actually cited.

Comment: By default `biblatex` (as well as BibTeX) only add those entries to the bibliography list that were actually cited with `\...cite` and friends in the text. You can override this behaviour and add all entries from the `.bib` file to the bibliography with `\nocite{*}`. With `biblatex` it is not too hard to separate the bibliography into works that were actually `\...cite`d and those that were only added to the bibliography because of `\nocite`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6967/35864.