# An extra bibliography section for recommended lectures

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning, biber, back-referencing

I've been asked now to add a "Recommended Lectures" section after the actual bibliography for my thesis. So, regardless whether I'm citing a reference in text or not, I must discern if it is actually used or is just a complementary, recommended lecture.

But I'm not sure how to manage that with my actual configuration... Basically, my tex file until now is like this:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
% !BIB program = biber

\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,spanish=spanish]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Legislacion.bib}
\addbibresource{ArticulosDidactica.bib}

\begin{document}

% Document body

\printbibliography[title={Referencias bibliográficas},heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

That has been working perfect for references. At the very moment I mentioned something with `\cite{reference}` (or related comand) it was shown at bibliography. But now I have to add another section and make each reference to appear in only one of both: or bibliography references or recommended lectures.

How can I do that?

Comment: In principle, what you want to achieve is provided by ``\nocite{reference}`, or better `\nocite{*}` to insert all references present in the `.bib` file.  Here the problem can be that do not want to `nocite\  everything, Any way, you need two separate bibliographies, which are provided by using two successive `\printbibliography` commands with different sets of options.

Comment: I think that's not a solution. `\nocite` prints items that are in the bib file despite they are not cited. That does not solve the fact that I must include another section. That does not distinguish in which section will be printed. In a thesis (one or two hundred of pages) is not handy go checking reference by reference each time. Example, when analizing an article I may mention a referenced topic because it is important, but without intention of focusing on it. Since it's a used citation, there's a `\cite{}`, but it's actually just a recommended lecture. @Jhor

Comment: You could add a keyword like *recommended* to the specific bibentries and then print them after your regular bibliography with the option `keyword=recommended`. (Of course, you should add them to your tex file previously using `nocite`)

Comment: you can use categories to distinguish the entries, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6977/2388