# Creating multiple bibliographies

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am working on a document which necessitates a creation of two bibliographies: one which lists further reading materials and another containing the bibliographic entries of all in-text citations.

I currently use `biblatex` keywords to do so. However, I need for the same reference (`smith15` in the following MWE) to show up in both bibliographies. How can I achieve such result?

**citations.bib**

```
@book{doe14,
  author = {John Doe},
  title = {Sample Title},
  date = 2014,
  publisher = {Sample Publisher},
}

@book{smith15,
  author = {Jane Smith},
  title = {Sample Title},
  date = 2015,
  publisher = {Sample Publisher},
  keywords = {custom},
}

@book{johnson16,
  author = {Steve Johnson},
  title = {Sample Title},
  date = 2016,
  publisher = {Sample Publisher},
}
```

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{citations.bib}

\begin{document}

% Main Text
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi pretium dictum efficitur \parencite{doe14, smith15, johnson16}.

% Custom Bibliography
\nocite{smith15}

\printbibliography[keyword={custom}, title={Custom Bibliography}]

\printbibliography[notkeyword={custom}]

\end{document}
```

**Current Output**

[image: 1]

**Expected Output**

`smith15` should appear in both bibliographies.

Comment: Do you want something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6967/35864?

Comment: In this example it is clear that `smith15` won't be shown in the second bibliography, because the code specifically asks the bibliography to ignore all entries with the keyword `custom`, which `smith15` has set. So you need a better way of telling LaTeX which entry to print where. This suggests that keywords are not the right course of action here.

Comment: @moewe, thank you for linking that thread. For now, I used `category={cited}` for the main bibliography and `keyword={custom}` for the custom bibliography; now `smith15` appears in both. I'm not sure whether there is a cleaner solution so I left this as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: The best solution depends on your exact use case and expectations. If you want all cited entries to go into one bibliography and only ever `\nocite` those entries that go into the other list, then I think https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6967/35864 is the cleanest solution and you won't even need keywords. If you have something more complex in mind, then you might need something more sophisticated. At least in the example and from what I understand so far I don't see the need for `keyword = {custom},` and think the linked solution would be enough - but there may be reasons for using it.